# XenDesktop 7 minimize/restore issue

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vdi, xendesktop

I'm evaluating Citrix Xen Desktop 7 and using VMWare vSphere as a hosting of virtual machines.
All works perfectly except multy-monitors workstations.
The problem is, that when user minimizes Citrix desktop session he can't restore it, he sees just black screen.
But, if user uses a single-monitor workstation the problem doesn't appear.
Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you done any research or troubleshooting yet?

Comment: I don't know how to troubleshoot the problem. If you can suggest any steps, please do. Thank you

Comment: You'll generally get more help if you've shown a little more effort in trying to solve the problem yourself first.